# Problem occurs when converting a C# struct to binary file (using BinaryWriter)

Tags: c#

I'm working on converting a C# `struct` to `bin` file. But something goes wrong when I check the `bin` file I made. It nearly halves the struct size ( 11 -> 6 )

Here is the code I wrote:

```
enum PublicVar : uint
    {
        LEN = 2U,
        CELL= 32U, ... 
    };

  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
  [Serializable]
    public struct MyStruct
    {
        public UInt16 Crc;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst= (int)PublicVar.LEN)]
        // LEN = 2U
        public UInt32[] Address;
        public byte Word;
    };

    MyStruct ex;

    var ex = new MyStruct();
    ex.Address = new UInt32[(uint)PublicVar.LEN];

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)// Using Winform
    {
        ex.Crc = 1;
        ex.Address = new UInt32[] { 16, 17};
        ex.Word = 2;


        byte[] getBytes(MyStruct str)
        {
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(str); //11
            byte[] arr = new byte[size]; 

            IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(str, ptr, true);
            Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, size);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
            return arr;
        }

        string filename = @"C:\test.bin";
        FileStream fs = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create);

        using (BinaryWriter wr = new BinaryWriter(fs))
        {
            wr.Write(getBytes(ex));
            wr.Flush();
            wr.Close();
            //wr.Write('\0');
        }
}
```

After running, the right format should be `01 00 10 00 00 00 11 00 00 00 02`.
But if I check the file, it shows as `01 10 00 11 00 d8`. (Made some trash value for byte type)

I don't know why this happen, so I used `wr.Write('\0');` under `wr.Write(getBytes(ex));`
And it works well!! `01 00 10 00 00 00 11 00 00 00 02 00` is written to the file.

But are there any other solutions for this problem? Because I only need the `bin` file for the `struct` with nothing else added.

Comment: If you isolate getBytes(ex) in an array variable before writing the file and adding the null byte, is it `01 00 10 00 00 00 11 00 00 00 02` or `01 10 00 11 00 d8`?

Comment: @Tyress 01 10 00 11 00 d8 appears.